# Proving binormal vector is the limiting position of perpendicular to tangent lines

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, frenet-frame

"Let $\alpha(s)$ be a regular curve. Verify that the the binormal vector $b(s_0)$ is the limiting position of the perpendicular to the tangent lines to $\alpha$ at $s_0$ and $s_1$ as $s_1$ tends to $s_0$."

I'm not really getting what the author means here. Am I supposed to prove that as $s_0$ approaches $s_1$, the plane determined by $\alpha(s_0)$ and the perpendicular line at $\alpha(s_1)$ approaches the osculating plane?

**EDIT**: Still no closer to figuring out precisely what "limiting position of the perpendicular the tangent lines" really means. Would be grateful for any help.

---

Thanks to @TedShifrin (whose patience was crucial for this), the exercise is solved and all my initial confusions are cleared.

Comment: Matheus, is this a bad English translation of Portuguese? :) Take the *plane* through $\alpha(s_0)$ perpendicular to $T(s_0)$ [the normal plane at $\alpha(s_0)$] and the normal plane at $\alpha(s_1)$, and, yes, find the limit of their intersection line.

Comment: @TedShifrin, no, actually. I did translate it, but it's completely faithful to the original text (almost verbatim... except, of course, for the fact it's in a different language).

But I do get what you're saying, thanks! A question, though: to find their intersection, do I just expand everything in coordinates, find the equation for the line and prove it's direction vector is $b(s_0)$ or is there an easier way?

Comment: How do you find the direction vector of the line of intersection of two planes?

Comment: The only thing I can come up with is $v = T(s_0) \times T(s_1)$, but I can't see how that helps me here. More specifically, how do I prove that $\lim_{s_1 \to s_0} v = b(s_0)$?

Comment: Cool. Take the unit vector and find its limit as $s_1 = s_0+h\to s_0$.

Comment: I'm sure there must be something trivial here I'm not seeing, but how does one prove that $\lim_{h \to 0} \cfrac{T(s_0) \times T(s_0+h)}{||T(s_0) \times T(s_0 +h )||} = b(s_0)$?  

I know that $b(s_0) = \cfrac{T \times T'}{|| T \times T'||}$, but I can't see how to get from one to the other.

Comment: Think about the Taylor expansion of $T$?

Comment: I still can't see how the limit evaluates to $b(s_0)$. I know that $T(s_0) =  T(0) + T'(0)s_0 + T''(0)\frac{(s_0)^2}{2} + \cdots$, but I tried working with that to compute the limit and it got a little hairy.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'll be honest with you: even though I've tried, for a while now, to prove that this limit evaluates to $b(s_0)$, I can't for the life of me shake off the (most likely naive and misguided) intuition that it should be equal to the $0$ vector. I've even tried expanding $T(s_0) \times T(s_0 + h)$ in the (pseudo)determinant and computing the limit of the resulting expression, but it leads me nowhere close to $b(s_0)$.

Comment: Hint, Matheus: What is $T(s_0)\times T'(s_0)$? Don't do any determinants. Just use properties of $\times$.

Comment: @TedShifrin $T(s_0) \times T'(s_0) = T(s_0) \times (k(s_0) N(s_0)) = k(s_0) b(s_0)$. In theory all I should have to do now is manipulate the earlier limit expression to look something like this (I know any multiple of $b(s_0)$ will do), but that's still giving me trouble. By the way, thanks for the patience.

Comment: That's why you pay me the big bucks :)  There's an interesting application of this concept later, when you get to surfaces (at least in my book) — to build a *flat* ruled surface that is tangent to a given surface along a given curve. As I said, write down the Taylor approximation and do the limit.

Comment: @TedShifrin It is indeed :) I do wanna move on to your chapter on surfaces as soon as possible, but I wanna do as many exercises of Keti's chapter on curves in $\mathbb{R^3}$ as I can (and some of yours as well) before. I haven't completed this one yet, though... unfortunately it's proven quite cumbersome to evaluate that limit. What property of the cross product (or any other helpful insight, really) could I have used earlier?

Comment: $T(s_0)\times \big(T(s_0)+T'(s_0)h + \dots\big)$ (say for $h>0$) made into a unit vector is what?

Comment: $T(s_0) \times (T(s_0) + T'(s_0)h + \cdots) = (T(s_0) \times T'(s_0))h + (T(s_0) \times T''(s_0)) \frac{h^2}{2} + \cdots$. The unit vector mentioned would be $v = \cfrac{(T(s_0) \times T'(s_0))h + (T(s_0) \times T''(s_0))\frac{h^2}{2}+ \cdots}{||(T(s_0) \times T'(s_0))h + (T(s_0) \times T''(s_0))\frac{h^2}{2} + \cdots||}$  And I'm guessing there is probably something I can assume to make my life easier here, because that expression is not pretty at all. Is there?

Comment: You're taking the limit as $h\to 0$, remember? :)

Comment: Sure. Doesn't that all go to $0$ as $h \to 0$, though?

Comment: Remember how you handle limits: Typically algebra is involved. You'll get this.

Comment: Ooooooh. I passed Calc I with the highest grades possible and forgot this. Damn it. Guess I really am pretty sleep deprived to make this kind of careless mistake. The limit is exactly $\cfrac{T(s_0) \times T'(s_0)}{||T(s_0) \times T'(s_0)||}$. Thanks a lot, I appreciate it! Turns out I did get it after all.

Comment: @TedShifrin If you want to post a summary of this discussion as an answer, I'll gladly accept it. I don't like leaving questions already solved without an answer, so I usually post them myself, but here I would feel pretty guilty :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $s_1=s_0+h$. The intersection line of the normal planes at $\alpha(s_0)$ and $\alpha(s_1)$ has direction vector $T(s_0)\times T(s_0+h)$. As $h\to 0$, it's clear that $\alpha(s_0)$ will be a point in the limiting intersection. The \limiting direction vector (defined up to scalar multiples) will be 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{T(s_0)\times T(s_0+h)}h &= T(s_0) \times \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{T(s_0+h)-T(s_0)}h \\ &= T(s_0)\times T'(s_0)= \kappa(s_0) T(s_0)\times N(s_0) \\ &= \kappa(s_0) B(s_0),
\end{align*}
as desired.